# Using Flutter and Dart, why String variable's value is changing over screen transfer?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, datetime

At my first screen this is the code and result:

```
appController.mydate=DateTime.parse(info.timestamp).toLocal().toString().substring(0, DateTime.parse(info.timestamp).toLocal().toString().length - 7).replaceAll("T", " ");
print(appController.mydate);
I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 13:08
I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 12:54
I/flutter (27269): 2022-08-01 11:46
I/flutter (27269): 2022-07-13 12:42
```

At my second screen this is the code and result:

```
print(widget.appController.mydate);
I/flutter (27269): 2022-07-13 12:42
```

It stores only the last value on transfer, i want all the values(dates).

Comment: Please share the value of info that you written in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is printing last date cause you display all date time in screen 1 ( As they printing in all at new line)

And you are passing last value only. So, I guess you are using for loop or something for printing in first screen.

Comment: thats right its a loop thanks